# ROS2 CPP file only second logger

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, rclcpp

For a specific ROS2 (humble) node that I'm working on I want to add a second logger that just logs to a file (preferably its own). Setting up a second logger is straightforward, as one can just call `rclcpp::get_logger('<logger-name>')`. I could, however, not find any way to set the logger up so that it just logs to its own file. I do not want the logger to log to the terminal at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Re. separate log files:

It is not currently possible to log to two separate files from one node.
To realize this, you'd have to implement an alternative [rcl_logging_interface](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_logging).

(Multiple nodes in different processes do log to different files but that is not your use case.)

Re. disabling logging to stdout:

It is possible to disable output to stdout with the ros-args flag `--disable-stdout-logs`. E.g. for the [demo_nodes_cpp example](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/rolling/demo_nodes_cpp):

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp list_parameters --ros-args --disable-stdout-logs
```

In case of the DEBUG loglevel, some messages for `rcl` and `rclcpp` are still shown, e.g.:

```
ros2 run  demo_nodes_cpp list_parameters --ros-args --log-level DEBUG --disable-stdout-logs
```

If you don't need DEBUG loglevel for `rcl` and `rclcpp` (e.g. you only need DEBUG for your nodes), then the stray stdout logmessages can avoided by specifying non-DEBUG loglevels for `rcl` and `rclcpp`:

```
ros2 run  demo_nodes_cpp list_parameters --ros-args --log-level DEBUG --disable-stdout-logs --log-level rcl:=INFO --log-level rclcpp:=INFO
```

**Longer answer:**

> Setting up a second logger is straightforward, as one can just call `rclcpp::get_logger('<logger-name>')`.

This is indeed what you'd expect based on the class name 'Logger', but it is not correct. An `rclcpp::Logger` does not perform any logging, it is just a [small class](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/7c1143dc1502d5dda99a3dfa17124a72dbaea90c/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/logger.hpp#L92) mainly holding a name and providing some methods such as `set_level(Level level)`, but nothing more. The logging is done solely through the log macros, e.g. `RCLCPP_INFO()`, which resolve to `rcutils` function calls.

A while ago, I dug through the whole logging code and wrote down an almost complete walktrough [in this document](https://github.com/jrutgeer/ROS2_assorted_docs/blob/main/ROS2_core/ROS2_logging.md).
Mind you, this is more or less a literal chronological writedown of digging through the code (i.e. not ideally structured as documentation) and there have been some changes to the code since I wrote that document, so it is not fully up to date anymore. Nevertheless: afaik it still is the best documentation on rclcpp logging currently availabe.

I won't go through the details here, but [this section](https://github.com/jrutgeer/ROS2_assorted_docs/blob/main/ROS2_core/ROS2_logging.md#rcl-output-handlers) describes the three current output handlers: to console / publish on topic rosout / to file. The 'to file' output handler is described in [this subsection](https://github.com/jrutgeer/ROS2_assorted_docs/blob/main/ROS2_core/ROS2_logging.md#external-library-spdlog). To allow for logging to multiple files you'd need to adapt the `rcl_logging_spdlog` library or write a similar library and load that as the log handler.

Comment: An alternative to writing a custom `rcl_logging_interface` could be to implement subscribers to `/rosout` and have those write the log messages to file. If you'd decide to go that route, be sure to read the [section on the `/rosout` publisher](https://github.com/jrutgeer/ROS2_assorted_docs/blob/main/ROS2_core/ROS2_logging.md#a-few-peculiarities-about-the-rosout-publisher) since named loggers do **not** output to `/rosout`.

Comment: Thank you! We're in the process of migrating something from our own framework to ROS and in our own framework it was natural to have multiple loggers (e.g. one with DEBUG log level going to file only and one with INFO level going to stdout and file), so I assumed that would be a use case that would be way more common and covered by default.

Comment: Ok that is an even more stringent requirement: a logger's log level is evaluated _before_  the log handler is called, and the [current log handler](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/7c1143dc1502d5dda99a3dfa17124a72dbaea90c/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/context.cpp#L134) does just call [each enabled handler](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/9a05fa65926673b2986175ff055215861e29bf5b/rcl/src/rcl/logging.c#L152-L162) without further discriminating on log level.